# Initializing C++ array in constant time

Tags: c++, visual-c++

```
char buffer[1000] = {0};
```

This initializes all 1000 elements to 0. Is this constant time? If not, why?

It seems like the compiler could optimize this to O(1) based on the following facts:

1. The array is of fixed size and known at compile time
2. The array is located on the stack, which means that presumably the executable could contain this data in the data segment of the executable (on Windows) as a chunk of data that is already filled with 0's.

Note that answers can be general to any compiler, but I'm specifically interested in answers tested on the MSVC compiler (any version) on Windows.

Bonus Points: Links to any articles, white papers, etc. on the details of this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What context is this? Static?

Comment: It makes no sense to talk about O notation and "compile time" in one paragraph

Comment: @n.m. I'm not referring to "compile time" as in compile duration or performance, I am referring to "compile time" to represent the moment of compilation, in other words, at the compilation phase, what information is known.

Comment: Arrays in C++ must have fixed constant size so however long the operation is, it's `O(1)` (in some sense) by definition.

Comment: @Robert Dailey: I'm talking about the same concept of compile time (aka phase) you and everybody else is talking about.

Comment: @n.m. At compile time, the code to initialize the list can be generated to run at O(n) or O(1) complexity at run time. It makes perfect sense to use them both in the same paragraph. Comments like yours add no value to questions.

Comment: The algorithmic complexity of the code is totally unrelated to whether it is compiled, interpreted or executed by some other, hitherto unknown means. If it can be done in O(1) at all, then a compiler can produce code that does it in O(1). If it cannot, it cannot. Well, when discussing a particular compiler, I guess you can say "it generates O(N) code where O(1) would suffice". I grant you that. When talking about algorithmic complexity of a *problem*, and the problem of initializing an array *is* a problem, compilers are just totally irrelevant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It will never be constant time, global or not. its true the compiler initializes that, but the operating system must load all the file into memory, which takes `O(n)` time.

Comment: Why are you talking about files?

Comment: @RobertDailey: Because the executable (your program) needs to be loaded into memory. Even if your data segment has 1000 zeros allocated in the executable, that executable needed to be mapped into memory, which is a linear time operation.

Comment: Dani is right. The array is either initialized to zeros in memory, or it is read from disk. But reading N zeros from disk is O(N) as well.

Comment: @RobertDailey: where does your program come from? it doesn't magically appear in memory. It must first be loaded from the executable, which would involve copying all the zeroes the compiler wrote.

Comment: @AlKepp: actually loading all zeroes from disk is much slower than `mem_set`, so I'm not sure the compiler will even put them all in file.

Comment: A compiler will put array of zeros to a file only if it is stupid or if it cannot do better way. For example when targetting COM file in MS-DOS environment.

Comment: In theory if the compiler allocated all zero statics in their own pages, then rather than having to zero pages on demand, the OS could map those pages using its pre-zeroed pages thus moving the constant time factor from the point of loading to some random point in time when the processor is otherwise idle.

Comment: It is only *sort of* a linear time operation. O(1) for a disk is most likely the sector size, O(1) for memory could be the cache line size, etc. Not quite sure this adequately answers the OP's question at hand. By this logic, `x = 1000` ought to be O(n) just in case the compiler decides to *count to 1000*...

Comment: @Dani Interesting, I hadn't thought about the actual process of loading the executable into memory. I phrased my question poorly in this regard, but I was more or less concerned about the stack frame for the function -- whether or not it was O(n) to initialize that array or not. Apparently it is :)

Comment: Here's a dumb question that I've been googling for a while, but what does constant time mean?

Answer (score 8):

If it's inside a function, no, it's not constant time.

Your second assumption isn't correct:

"The array is located on the stack, which means that presumably the executable could contain this data in the data segment of the executable (on Windows) as a chunk of data that is already filled with 0's."

The stack isn't already filled with zeros. It's filled with junk leftover from previous function calls.

So it's not possible to do it in `O(1)` because it will have to zero it.

Answer (score 6):

It can be O(1) only as a global variable. If it is a local variable (on stack) it is O(n) where n is the size of array.

Stack is a shared memory, you need to actively zero always you want to have 1000 zeros in there. An array like you defined is not implemented as a pointer to data segment, it is 1000 variables on the stack and must be initialized in O(1000).

EDIT: Dani is right, I have to fix my statement: If it is a global array, it is initialized when program starts. And it is O(n) as well.

Comment: A common idiom if framing is involved is to move the stack pointer to make space and then come behind to apply values to local variables.

Comment: Even if its global, the operating system still needs to load it, see my answer

Comment: I thought data from the data segment is copied to the stack for each function. I'm not an expert on the low level details like this but I thought for arrays it was 1 batch copy to the stack.. i.e. 'push' 1000 bytes onto the stack as one, optimized operation. I didn't know it was doing a single push for each element. Seems like that could be optimized somehow...

Comment: @RobertDailey: Even if the data segment was copied, that would still be linear time. You'd just have a bigger data segment to copy. (But that's not what happens anyway)

Comment: @RobertDailey: no, usually the frame pointer (EBP) is pushed onto the stack. The stack pointer (ESP) is then saved in the frame pointer. The stack pointer is then decremented by the number of bytes required to store the local variables (aligned). After this is done any initial values for local variables are assigned. In this specific case using the defaults VC++ 2k10 uses `memset` to zero out the memory (even without optimization).

Comment: @AlKepp: a minor nit; 1000 bytes can be written in less than O(1000) time on any machine with a word size greater than 1 byte.

Comment: @sixlettervariables: Do you understand what exactly means O-notation? What you present is still an O(N) example. Or O(1000) for 1000 items. :-)

Comment: Actually O(1000) is equivalent to O(1), you can go from one to another by modulating the 'c' value. O(n) means that there is some value 'c' at which the complexity will NEVER converge back to the graph of an O(1) algorithm.

Comment: Yes, that's why we always talk about N items even when we know there are only 1000 ones. The point is that when sixlettervariables wrote: "1000 bytes can be written in less than O(1000) time on any machine with a word size greater than 1 byte." it is still O(N), i.e. linear and not better. I hope we understand each other, and an endless discussion is not needed here.

Comment: @AlKepp: I'm aware, my nit was with your "...must be initialized in O(1000)." I was trying to point out what Michael did in much more clear fashion.

Answer (score 1):

> The array is located on the stack, which means that presumably the executable could contain this data in the data segment of the executable (on Windows) as a chunk of data that is already filled with 0's.

What if you recurse into the function that defines array? The global DATA segment would need to have a copy of this array for each function call to allow each function to have its own array to work over. The compiler would have to run your code to decide the maximum recursions are going to happen.

Also what happens when you have multiple threads in your program and each calls foo? All the sudden you have shared stuff in DATA that has to be locked. The locking might cause more performance problems than getting rid of the initialization.

I wouldn't worry about it too much too. Most platforms have fairly efficient ways of zero filling memory. Unless you profile it and find a problem, don't sweat it.

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, assumption 2 is wrong. Stack variables are allocated at run-time in O(1) time but are not normally initialised unless you're running a debug build.

```
PUSH ebp
MOV  ebp, esp
SUB  esp, 10
// function body code goes here
```

Here, the stack pointer 'esp' is decremented by 10 to make room for some local function variables. They are not initalised... that would require a loop.

[This](http://unixwiz.net/techtips/win32-callconv-asm.html) article seems friendly enough.

Answer (score -1):

If it's a global static, the "constant" here is ZERO - initialization is done at COMPILE TIME.

Comment: How are you going to allocate a block of 1000 contigious zeros on a machine that doesn't even exist yet??